# Using methods to access classes and the instantiate them

Tags: php, class, methods, get, instantiation

I have stored the class I want to instantiate in a variable that is accessible via get and set methods:

```
private $myClass;

public function setClass($myClass) {$this->myClass = $myClass;}
public function getClass() {return $this->myClass;}
```

Now later on I want to instantiate this class using the get method:

```
$instance = new $getClass()();
```

And also work with some of it's static attributes:

```
$staticAttr = $getClass()::$attr;
```

But both of these lines throw errors, I think I've found a solution but I'm really not certain and I feel that my problem is some fundamental lack of understand about how to do this. Or perhaps it is just awful practice and so highly discouraged? How best should I go about approaching this?

Comment: Some context on why you are doing this would be helpful.

Comment: I have a 'group' class that instantiates a whole load of other classes on demand. I was attempting to generalize it to save rewriting any code.

Comment: I have the feeling this idea _is_ really awful and should be discouraged. You should explain what you are about to do. I think there is way too much dynamic access involved: A dynamic classname pointing to a dynamically instantiated object, with dynamically accessed static properties... Your class probably does too much different stuff and should be separated into parts.

Comment: Hi Sven, interesting that you should say that because actually my entire system is dynamic. I'm working on an entirely object oriented server side approach to presenting webpages but using extensions of a single class 'an entity'. At the moment it's pretty rough so yes I probably have way to much in one class for further extensions and it should be broken down, however the base 'EntityGroup' class has less than 100 lines and just acts as a way to display lists of other entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP's syntax does not allow for this.  In order to get this working, you just need to store the class name to a variable first:

```
$class_name = $obj->getClass();
$instance = new $class_name();
```

The same goes for accessing the static property:

```
$class_name = $obj->getClass();
$staticAttr = $class_name::$attr;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong

```
$instance = new $getClass()();
```

Instead do this

```
$getClass = "classname";

$instance = new $getClass();
```

for static functions do this

```
$getClass::getMethod();
```

For static members

```
$getClass::$attr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tweaking your code to a working object:

```
class someObject {

  private $myClass;

  public function setClass($myClass) {$this->myClass = $myClass;}
  public function getClass() {return $this->myClass;}

}
```

Sample

```
$a = new someObject();

$a->setClass(new stdClass());
var_dump($a->getClass());
```

You can access `$a->getClass()->property`, for static properties:

```
class Foo {
  public static $a = 'bar';
}

$a->setClass(new Foo());
$class = $a->getClass();

var_dump($class::$a);
```